# Babel 7, Typescript, Webpack 4 does not transpile Typescript into Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to achieve a baseline Babel 7 + Typescript configuration using the new way so that Babel 7 would strip off the Typescript types and bundle the Javascript.

Being a rookie with the toolchain I seem to have to roadblock and cannot figure out the problem properly, let alone the solution. Or put otherwise, I don't seem to find a good starting point project from Internet nor construct one myself so I could iterate towards a more comprehensive solution with the usual things like minification and browser list polyfilling.

It seems the start is the most difficult one, so my hope is someone's eyes are much better trained and maybe can offer a hint how to get

The complete solution is at [here](https://github.com/veikkoeeva/WebPackTest/blob/master/WebPackTest/webpack.config.js) (it's ASP.NET Core, but the web things should run without it too). Specifically the `webpack.config.js` looks like

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const bundleOutputDir = "./wwwroot/dist";

module.exports = (env) =>
{
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
return [{
mode: isDevBuild ? "development" : "production",
stats: { modules: false },
resolve: {
  extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
  modules: ["App", "node_modules"]
},
output: {
  path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
  publicPath: "dist/",
  filename: "[name].js"
},
module: {
  rules: [
    { test: /\.ts$/i, include: /App/, use: "ts-loader?silent=true" },
    { test: /\.html$/i, use: "html-loader" },
    { test: /\.css$/i, use: isDevBuild ? "css-loader" : "css-loader?minimize" },
    { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: "url-loader?limit=25000" }
  ]
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerMode: "static", reportFilename: "./../../bundle_report.html" }),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({ IS_DEV_BUILD: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild) })
].concat(isDevBuild ? [
  new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
    filename: "[file].map",
    noSources: true,
    moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, "[resourcePath]")
  })
] : [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      uglifyOptions: {
        ie8: false,
        ecma: 8
      },
      output: {
        comments: false,
        beautify: false
      },
      compress: false,
      warnings: false,
      parallel: {
        cache: true
      }
    })
  ])
  }];
};
```

1. What could be wrong with this since it doesn't produce `App.js` in `wwwroot/dist`?
2. Note, I should remove *Uglify* and configure *babel-preset-minify* (the package is included).
3. Note, I would like to have the fullest typemaps.
4. Webpack-bundle-analyzer generates heaps of warnings about Babel compatibility, should probably be removed.

<edit: To update, it looks like some of the things in web is a bit outdated information. As a note, I'll look into

- [babel-loader (Webpack)](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) and
- [wanago.io Webpack 4 course](https://wanago.io/2018/07/16/webpack-4-course-part-one-entry-output-and-es6-modules/) which appears to be a very good one. :)

<edit: Just in case someone stumbles here [terser-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/298#issuecomment-409963409) might be the way to go with Webpack since there [might a problem with babel-minify-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babel-minify-webpack-plugin/issues/68).

<edit: Here's a scruffy version that produces a JS otuput from the sample TS file. The code in GH will be revised later.

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const bundleOutputDir = "./wwwroot/dist";
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = (env) => {
const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
return [{
    mode: isDevBuild ? "development" : "production",
    stats: { modules: false },
    entry: {
        app: './App/App'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(bundleOutputDir),
        publicPath: "dist",
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".json"],
        modules: ["App", "node_modules"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(ts)|(js)$/, exclude: /(node_modules)/, use: { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] } } },
            { test: /\.html$/i, use: "html-loader" },
            //{ test: /\.css$/i, use: isDevBuild ? "css-loader" : "css-loader?minimize" },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: "url-loader?limit=25000" },
            { test: /\.js$/, use: ["source-map-loader"], enforce: "pre" },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: [{ loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, options: { publicPath: '../' } }, "css-loader"] }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ IS_DEV_BUILD: JSON.stringify(isDevBuild) }),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
            {
                filename: "[name].css",
                chunkFilename: "[id].css"
            })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: "[file].map",
            noSources: true,
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, "[resourcePath]")
        })
    ] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
                uglifyOptions: {
                    ie8: false,
                    ecma: 8
                },
                output: {
                    comments: false,
                    beautify: false
                },
                compress: false,
                warnings: false,
                parallel: {
                    cache: true
                }
            })
        ])
}];
};
```

Comment: Either use Babel or Typescript, never seen these two mixed together. Typescript is much like Babel with additional optional type checking

Comment: Babel 7 should be able to do it. See at https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/08/27/7.0.0 and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/08/27/typescript-and-babel-7/ . It works by just stripping of TS information and then working normally.  I see here are some Babel + TS questions here too, but more specific problems. Maybe I should try to see what's in them. :)